# Select parts of a nlobjSearchResult

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a large nlobjSearchResultSet object with over 18,000 "results".

Each result is a pricing record for a customer. There may be multiple records for a single customer.

As 18000+ records is costly in governance points to do mass changes, I'm migrating to a parent (customer) record and child records (items) so I can make changes to the item pricing as a sublist.

As part of this migration, is there a simple command to select only the nlapiSearchResult objects within the big object, which match certain criteria (ie. the customer id).

This would allow me to migrate the data with only the one search, then only subsequent create/saves of the new record format.

IN a related manner, is there a simple function call to return to number of records contained in a given Netsuite record? For % progress context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the total number of records, the only way is do a saved search, an ideal way to do such search is using `nlobjSearch`

Below is a sample code for getting infinite search Results and number of records

```
var search = nlapiLoadSearch(null, SAVED_SEARCH_ID).runSearch();
var res = [],
    currentRes;

var i = 0;

while(i % 1000 === 0){
  currentRes = (search.getResults(i, i+1000) || []);
  res = res.concat(currentRes );
  i = i + currentRes.length;
}
```

`res.length` or `i` will give you the total number of records and `res` will give you all the results.

Comment: Ideally I wanted to retrieve the number of records without a loop. but no worries, that will have to do, just thought there may have been an easier way

Comment: AFAIK, that isn't possible, this is what I can think of

Comment: Otherwise, is there a simplistic method to the first section of my question?

Comment: once, the resultset is fetched you can't add criteria, you got to edit your saved search iteself, if saved search does not support the criteria you are looking for, you cannot do that

Comment: OK. Might just have to filter through with a loop, an array, and a bit of pushing. Thanks.

Comment: you might find `filter()` method of Array useful for that purpose https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2):

you can actually get the number of rows by running the search with an added aggregate column. A generic way to do this for a saved search that doesn't have any aggregate columns is shown below:

```
var res = nlapiSearchRecord('salesorder', 'customsearch29', null, 
    [new nlobjSearchColumn('formulanumeric', null, 'sum').setFormula('1')]);
var rowCount = res[0].getValue('formulanumeric', null, 'sum');
console.log(rowCount);
```